# Cassandra COPY TO with timestamp

Tags: cassandra, cql

My goal is to move rows from one Cassandra 2.0 table to another with different primary key. To ensure data consistency I will need to insert them with original timestamps (`USING TIMESTAMP`). I planed to use `COPY TO`/`COPY FROM` or just `COPY TO` and custom import from CSV.

Is there a way to copy rows with timestamps? `unixTimestampOf()` on TimeUUID column doesn't work saying "Improper COPY command".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Beware, `COPY TO` currently uses `SELECT` with `LIMIT 99999999`. You can easily get “Request did not complete within rpc_timeout.” against a large data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to do so using `COPY TO/FROM`. 
But it's possible to obtain a timestamp for a *column* using `WRITETIME` function

http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html#selectSelection